# How to display only one type of google map markers at a time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, types, google-maps-markers, markers

In the below code , I have two features , schools and restaurants . I have two buttons on the map , click of schools displays markers of schools and removes markers of restaurants and on click of restaurants displays restaurants and schools markers should be removed. I am setting the markers to null before calling the places Service but still it doesnt work. Any help  is much appreciated.

```
export class MortmapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  getlocation: { origin: { latitude: any; longitude: any; }; };
  srcOriginLatitude: any;
  srcOriginLongitude: any;
  mapArrayList: any = [];
  zoom: number;
  markers : any = [];

  constructor(private zone: NgZone, private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {

    mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.initMap();
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let originLat, originLng;
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        originLat = position.coords.latitude;
        originLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.getlocation = {
          origin: { latitude: originLat, longitude: originLng }
        };
        this.srcOriginLatitude = this.getlocation.origin.latitude;
        this.srcOriginLongitude = this.getlocation.origin.longitude;
      });
    }
    this.zoom = 14;
  }


  initMap() {

    var myLatLng = { lat: parseFloat(this.srcOriginLatitude), lng: parseFloat(this.srcOriginLongitude) };
    var myStyles = [
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
          { visibility: "off" }
        ]
      }
    ];
    map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 15,
      gestureHandling: 'none',
      styles: myStyles,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });

    // Create a div to hold the control.
    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

    //### Add a button on Google Maps ...
    var controlMarkerUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlMarkerUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlMarkerUI.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    controlMarkerUI.style.height = '28px';
    controlMarkerUI.style.width = '25px';
    controlMarkerUI.style.marginLeft = '10px';
    controlMarkerUI.style.marginTop = '10px';
    controlMarkerUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
    // controlMarkerUI.id = "schoolsTag";
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlMarkerUI);
    controlMarkerUI.addEventListener('click', this.getRestaurantList);


    //### Add a button on Google Maps ...
    var controlTrashUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlTrashUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlTrashUI.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    controlTrashUI.style.height = '28px';
    controlTrashUI.style.width = '25px';
    controlTrashUI.style.marginLeft = '60px';
    controlTrashUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
    controlTrashUI.id = "mosqueTag";
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlTrashUI);

    controlTrashUI.addEventListener('click', this.getSchoolsList);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(controlDiv);
  }

  getRestaurantList() {
  //   var markers = [];
    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    let originLat, originLng;

    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        originLat = position.coords.latitude;
        originLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.getlocation = {
          origin: { latitude: originLat, longitude: originLng }
        };
        this.srcOriginLatitude = this.getlocation.origin.latitude;
        this.srcOriginLongitude = this.getlocation.origin.longitude;
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: { lat: this.srcOriginLatitude, lng: this.srcOriginLongitude },
          radius: 10000,
          type: ['restaurant']
        }, (results, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

               for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
                this.markers[i].setMap(null);

              }

              // markers = [];

              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                console.log(" Places ", place);
                var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: place.geometry.location,
                  icon: './assets/images/marker_inactive.png',
                });
                marker.setMap(map);
                this.markers.push(marker);

              }

            }
          });
      });


    }
  }

  getSchoolsList() {
    //  var markers = [];
    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    let originLat, originLng;
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        originLat = position.coords.latitude;
        originLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.getlocation = {
          origin: { latitude: originLat, longitude: originLng }
        };
        this.srcOriginLatitude = this.getlocation.origin.latitude;
        this.srcOriginLongitude = this.getlocation.origin.longitude;
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: { lat: this.srcOriginLatitude, lng: this.srcOriginLongitude },
          radius: 10000,
          type: ['school']
        }, (results, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

               for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
                 this.markers[i].setMap(null);

               }

           //    this.markers = [];


            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              var place = results[i];
              console.log(" Places... ", place);
              var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                icon: './assets/images/marker_active.png',
              });
              marker.setMap(map);


             this.markers.push(marker);

            }
          }
            //  }

        });
      });

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? This is not a good enough description of the issue.

Comment: Okay , First when i click on one button , getRestaurantList() will be called and it displays markers of all restaurants , Next if i click on the second button , I am trigerring getSchoolsList () which displays markers of all schools. The problem here is the markers of restaurants should be removed and only markers of schools should be displayed and vice versa. But in my case, markers are not getting cleared and as a result , both schools and restaurant list of markers are shown. Also I am setting markers[i].setMap(null); before call of service.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declare the `var markers = [];` array in each function which results in the array being only available in the function scope (`markers` array defined in `getRestaurants()` is only available there, and the same goes for the array defined in `getSchools()`).

Define your `var markers = [];` in the **global scope** (and remove the declarations in the 2 functions). This way the variable will be available in both functions and your code should run fine.

Comment: I have added the global scope and removed the local scope , but i get error "cannot read property of undefined" Added the updated code . I get error in if  condition -- (this.markers.length > 0)

Comment: If i remove the local scope and add global scope , it is expecting to add this.markers everywhere , and as a result i get error cannot read property push of undefined

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows to reproduce the issue. The code you posted is **not** complete. How did you declare the global var? Where? And why did you modify other parts of your code now? It's **obvious** your code isn't going to work as you now put everything in that `if (this.markers.length > 0)` condition... what do you expect? Its length **will** be 0 if it's empty and nothing will happen!

Comment: I have pasted the complete code now . Please check. I added this to markers because it was throwing error " Cannot find name 'markers'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.markers'" After adding this , i get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I don't know Angular so I don't know how you are supposed to declare that markers array. What I know is that a properly declared empty array will not trigger the error you mention when checking its length. After you have removed the markers from the map (`markers[i].setMap(null)`) you should also empty `this.markers` as removing markers from the map won't remove them from the array. But that's yet another issue in your code and it's unrelated to the issue you mentioned in your last comment.